# Syslog filled with "@"-sign, Server not reachable

Tags: 16.04, server, syslog

today something happend to my ubuntu 16.04 server running plesk onxy.
the server was unreachable, so i did a hard reset.

after looking into /var/log/syslog, something strange was shown:
[syslog-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6nEv.png)
[kern.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uRYW.png)

Did anyone else has seen this before? The hard-reset of the server was on 23:23:51, so the Kernel Messages seems to be "normal". But the really strange party are those @-signs and there was no log during 23:06 and 23:23. 
Any idea what happend on my server?

if you need more information feel free to ask me!

Thanks in advice

Comment: `^@` represents a null byte. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation

Comment: This happens a lot in the case of hard power off.  Usually represents corruption/half written lines.  I'd examine `/var/log/syslog`, and **also** `/var/log/kern.log`.  The null bytes by themselves really don't tell you anything unfortunately. :/

Comment: hi, i added the kern.log file. Can this be cause by my veeam backup?

Comment: if the answer here is useful for you. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320977